# Deploy MAAS, Juju, Openstack

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have look in to dozens on online document but none give me the exact steps and recommendation for deploying MAAS, Juju and OpenStack on Ubuntu.

There's plenty of documentation available but none discuss the whole project in one.

Can someone point me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to find a single place that provides all the details.

However, I can help to some extent.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maas
sudo maas-region-admin createadmin
sudo apt-get install etherwake
```

To get the version of the current MAAS installed

```
apt-cache policy maas{,-dns,-dhcp} | grep Installed -B1 -A1
```

In `/etc/maas/templates/power/ether_wake.template`, make the following changes:

```
#elif [ -x /usr/bin/wakeonlan ]
#then
#    /usr/bin/wakeonlan $mac_address
elif [ -x /usr/sbin/etherwake ]
then
   sudo /usr/sbin/etherwake -i eth0 $mac_address
```

In `/etc/sudoers.d/99-maas-sudoers` add the following line at the end:

```
maas ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/etherwake
```

Enable IP forwarding on MAAS server:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -A FORWARD -i <interface without internet> -o <interface with internet> -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A FORWARD -i <interface with internet> -o <interface without internet> -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <interface with internet> -j MASQUERADE
```

Include `127.0.0.1` in the list of DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf on MAAS server.

```
sudo apt-get install openstack
sudo openstack-install
```

The above list of commands should successfully install Openstack Autopilot.
You may also refer to the github issues on MAAS-JUJU-Autopilot at https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer

Comment: Specify a storage device to be able to deploy this node.
Mount the root '/' filesystem to be able to deploy this node. .....................i thought i have commissioned both nodes before it ready ... should i check my .... FYI i configure RAID on both server ... is that OK or should i remove RAID .... ?????

Comment: i think i have no issue with installing , my issue is that MAAS complaine that i need to commission the nodes before it's hard disk or storage can be visible to MAAS. But the node is on READY state with no problem when commissioning ..... can you help please

Comment: Are the hard disks identified by MAAS??  If not, then check your BIOS, you may have to enable the hard drive slots after inserting them. Confirm if BIOS has detected the hard drives.

Comment: i am sure the hard drive is detect by BIOS. I configured RAID in the server and encounter the problem, then i delete all logical drive and try again still MAAS does not seems to identified the hard disk. It's check run the command juju bootstrap result with error complain about the file system etc etc ... maybe MAAS does not recognize my hard disk or so ....

Comment: I did not encounter any problems while commissioning/ deploying a Dell PowerEdge R415 with 1TB HDD with MAAS. Well then, I have nothing else inform.

Comment: i have not come across anything that talks about pre setup for HDD or any storage for MAAS to identify after commisionning a node ... do you have anything in mind i can read regarding HDD storage setup before MAAS commissioning a node

Comment: See if this helps you: https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/920

Comment: @ saisrinivas have not find anyting usefull yet ... i have file a bug with the issue but no answer yet .... anything else you can thing of .... do you have any document regarding hard disk support by MAAS etc etc or any kind of specific setup .... the strange thing is my CPU and RAM are recognize OK by MAAS, it's only my storage for the two different nodes i have is zero but MAAS does not complain when they were successfully commissioned to READY state

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a single guide to point you towards, mainly due to the [size of the project](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/figures/2/figures/osog_0001.png) and subsequent ways it can be tailored for an individual’s needs. The question itself spans four different software projects and multiple fields of technology including networking, virtualisation and storage configuration.

The most basic of guides can be found on Ubuntu’s [Installing Canonical’s OpenStack Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot) page. While at the other end of the spectrum you have Openstack’s [Installation Guide for Ubuntu](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/openstack-ops_preface.html). Then once you are up and running you can then use Openstack’s [Operations Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/index.html)

The best attempt at an overall guide is from the [Openstack in the basement](http://www.openstackbasement.com/home) project and all his [Ubuntu Openstack install](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwE-ZwWkNw8GIfxfIBcbumw/search?query=Ubuntu+Openstack+install+step) videos.

To make things simpler people make use of the [Openstack installer](http://openstack.astokes.org/) which handles Juju for you which is why a lot of guides don't mention any Juju configuration.

Comment: thanks i will check this out and let you know how it goes ...

Comment: I have follow and i have a problem with juju bootstrap showing from log  ... it says error with my storage ... when looking at my nodes i can see it is in ready state with core and RAM defined but 0 to both Disk and Storage ... Is there any particular setting on my BIOS for my disks or anything ....please help

Comment: Search nodes
Submit
FQDN  MAC Power Status Owner Cores RAM (GiB) Disks Storage (GB)
ACER-PC-FG.KalianetCLOUD.to  Ready  2 1 0 0.0
HP-SRV-FG.KalianetCLOUD.to  Ready  4 2 0 0.0   .... here is my nodes state on my maas

Comment: When clicking on a nodes here is error on both of them ................Storage
No storage information. Commissioning this node will gather the storage information.
Specify a storage device to be able to deploy this node.
Mount the root '/' filesystem to be able to deploy this node. .....................i thought i have commissioned both nodes before it ready ... should i check my .... FYI i configure RAID on both server ... is that OK or should i remove RAID .... ?????

Comment: Hi @MaileLatamai this looks like a separate issue to the question you originally asked. Make sure you [choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to the problem](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) you asked about in the question then create a new question.

Comment: @A Dark Divided Gem i have not choose any answer co's i have not found as a solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a single document which describes all this, it is here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/en/Intro.html

Beware that it is a bit outdated with respect to some topics as it was written two years ago.

Similar documentation exists for the autopilot installer:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/